# pass value from viewbag or viewdata to jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I created an application, in which I want to pass a value from `ViewBag` or `ViewData` to jQuery. Why is the value in jQuery  always null?? This is my code:

My Controller

```
var data =  _RoomRateService.GetDataForEdit(
                                      Convert.ToInt32(Session["RoomTypeID"]),
                                      Breakfast);

var insertNewRate = _RoomRateService.insertNewRateFromList(
                    Convert.ToString(Session["RoomTypeID"]), 
                    Breakfast, 
                    CheckInTo, 
                    data.CurrCode, 
                    SingleRate, 
                    DoubleRate,
                    TripleRate, 
                    Commission, 
                    Allotment, 
                    CloseSelling, FreeSell);

ViewBag.test = data.RoomType.RoomTypeName;
```

My jQuery

```
if(RoomTypeName == "")
     {
        tr.find("#lblRoomType-"+$(this).attr('id')).text("@ViewBag.Test");
     }
     else
     {
        tr.find("#lblRoomType-"+$(this).attr('id')).text(RoomTypeName);
     }
```

Can some one tell me where's my fault?

Comment: Check case of you dynamic property. You created a `test` property but you are accessing a `Test` property which will always be null

Comment: i already change Viewbag.Test to Viewbag.test, but the value still not pass to view

Comment: Not sure whats happening there but did you try using ViewData["Test"]? Did you check whether there is any value in the `data.RoomType.RoomTypeName` ?

Comment: with viewdata is same with viewbag.. value is not pass to view. in data.RoomType.RoomTypeName just have one value

Comment: Try changing @ViewBag.test to @(ViewBag.test)

Comment: Even if you don't put it in jQuery and write it in simple <div> or any where in html does it appear as a null or it is just happens when you try to put the value in jquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using TempData

Controller

```
TempData["Key"]=Yourdata;
```

View

```
 tr.find("#lblRoomType-"+$(this).attr('id')).text("@(TempData["Key"])");
```